# Generic user reference for hyperlink in word doc

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, hyperlink

Trying to make a table in word with links to specific pages in a PDF. I've gotten the PDF to open just how i want it, but need this to work for multiple users, here's an example of what i've tried that doesn't work.

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Dropbox\Examplefile.pdf#page=5
```

Everyone has the same path to the file on dropbox, but can't seem to reference the current user in the hyperlink.

Looking to avoid any VBA or macros.